# How to use an instance of a Form as a field of my own defined class in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I have defined a class like this:

```
class visualDisplay : IDisplay
{
    //Fields

    Form1 _form;
    Thread _displayThread;

    //Methods

    public visualDisplay()
    {
        _displayThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(initialize));
        _displayThread.Start();
        //initialize();
    }

    [STAThread]
    void initialize()
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();

        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Application.Run( _form = new Form1());
    }
}
```

I want to make an instance of a form and use it. But if call the `initialize()` method in the main thread (As it is commented above), I won't be able to run the rest of my code until I close the form.
On the other hand if I call it in the new thread which I defined (`displayThread`), It will be like there is no Form at all and when I want to use `_form`, I'll get the **Null reference exception** as below:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

So is there any way to fix this?

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/447156)

Comment: Well lets walk trough this code - you assign _form in parallel thread, in the meantime you continue with execution and (probably) access the _form variable - it will be null until the initialize() method finishes. Also your _form variable is not marked as volatile.

Comment: Your code working fine.. then what's the problem?

Comment: No it's not working fine. I think what I really want is to create an instance of a form in my own class and control it myself. I want it to display whatever I want whenever I want. That means some other piece of code should do the processing and tell '_form' to display it. I don't want my code to run by any event like '_form_load' event or 'button1_Click' event because the form should not control anything. it should just display when I tell him so.

Comment: Something else that may solve my problem. Shouldn't `[STAThread]` take care of all multithreading stuff like the **Cross-thread operation** ? But it's not working so I have to use a new thread and then I'll have **Cross-thread operation** problems.